# Tracking of attribute change

Tags: sql, oracle, tracking

I'm not DBA and cannot implement triggers, nor use CDC!

In staging area I do have a PRODUCTS table with the following columns: `PROD_ID, ATTR1_ID, ATTR2_ID, CREATED_BY, UPDATED_BY`. When app user changes product's attribute #1 the `ATTR1_ID` is changed and user's ID is saved in `UPDATED_BY` column. I need information who and when changed the attribute #1. Application does not track changes so I need to do it on my own in background. I created one history table for tracking ATTR1 changes with columns `PROD_ID, ATTR1_ID, UPDATED_BY, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO`

Data in this table should look like:

```
PROD_ID  ATTR1_ID   DATE_FROM     DATE_TO
      1       100  20.02.2021      <null>
      2       200  21.02.2021  22.02.2021   <-- attribute changed on 22.02.2021 from 200 to 201
      2       201  22.02.2021      <null>
      3       100  23.02.2021      <null>   <-- new product started
```

I intend to create PRODUCTS_OLD table for previous day data and PRODUCTS_NEW for current day data. Then I intend to copy PRODUCTS data into PRODUCTS_NEW table every day. Using MINUS operator I can see changes between new and old (yesterday) table. After detecting changes and inserting/updating information about that in separate history table I copy new data into old table and repeat this every day.

What is the best way to do all this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the issue you have? What is the code you've triesd and what was wrong with it? Or is this a question about application desing?

Comment: With this approach, if the table will be change several times per day, you'll see and record only the last modification user.

Comment: Exactly _why_ can't you use a trigger?  If you cannot use triggers, and you cannot use CDC, then what _can_ you do?  Can you create a procedure? Can you use dbms_scheduler to run a procedure on schedule? Can you modify the code (application) that is changing these attributes?